# How do I automatically upgrade Silverlight 3 out-of-browser application?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, automation, upgrade

How do I automatically upgrade Silverlight 3 applications and start the new upgraded version without user interaction?

I know that I can download and upgrade to new versions of the Silverlight OOB-app using Application.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync() but I don't know how to restart the application after that.

(The Silverlight application runs on a computer (more like a terminal/appliance) with no keyboard or mouse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't.

These isn't a mechanism to auto shut down an OOB app. The only general option is to display a pop-up once the update is complete asking the user to re-start the application but that sounds like it's probably not suitable in your situation

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way of auto-restarting an OOB application, I'm wondering if we can't just change the "MainPage.xaml" and move the user to a new page that won't let them do anything and have a prompt there that they must close out and restart the application?